# Use env variables inside cloudformation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

i have an amplify app with multiple branches.

I have added an custom cloudformation template with `amplify add custom`

It looks like:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": { "env": { "Type": "String" } },
  "Resources": {
    "db": {
      "Type": "AWS::Timestream::Database",
      "Properties": { "DatabaseName": "dev_db" }
    },
    "timestreamtable": {
      "DependsOn": "db",
      "Type": "AWS::Timestream::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "DatabaseName": "dev_db",
        "TableName": "avg_16_4h",
        "MagneticStoreWriteProperties": { "EnableMagneticStoreWrites": true },
        "RetentionProperties": {
          "MemoryStoreRetentionPeriodInHours": "8640",
          "MagneticStoreRetentionPeriodInDays": "1825"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {},
  "Description": "{\"createdOn\":\"Windows\",\"createdBy\":\"Amplify\",\"createdWith\":\"8.3.1\",\"stackType\":\"custom-customCloudformation\",\"metadata\":{}}"
}
```

You can see there is a field called `DatabaseName`. In my amplify app i have written an env variable named `TIMESTREAM_DB` and i want to use it inside of this cloudformation file.

Is this possible or do i need to write it all by hand in it?

Comment: How does your Amplify app use the template? Is it calling the API to create a stack?

Comment: @Parsifal i have 3 branches, whenever i push a branch it deploys an stack. The problem is that timestream is not an part of amplify so i need a custom clodformationtemplate. I want 3 different timestream databases for each branch 1 database. My idea was to save the db name as env variable inside of amplify and so it gets written inside the template when it gets pusehd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates cannot access arbitrary env vars. Instead, CloudFormation injects deploy-time values into a template with [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

Amplify helpfully adds the `env` variable as a parameter.  A la the [Amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/custom/cloudformation/), use the `env` value as the `AWS::Timestream::Database` name suffix:

```json
"DatabaseName": "Fn::Join": [ "", [ "my-timestream-db-name-", { "Ref": "env" } ] ]
```

The `AWS::Timestream::Table` resource also requires a `DatabaseName` parameter.  You could repeat the above, but it's more DRY to get the name [via the Database's Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-timestream-database.html#aws-resource-timestream-database-return-values):

```json
"DatabaseName": { "Ref" : "db" }
```

Comment: When i change the name the old timestream DB gets erased with all of its data and a new one gets created. Is it possible to keep the data in the renaming process? Is there some documentation about this?

Comment: @bill.gates Changing a CloudFormation resource's name always results in [replacement behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-update-behaviors.html).  The old resource gets deleted.  Some storage resources have a [DeletionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) attribute to retain the old resource outside the stack.  I don't know if the Timestream resources have this attribute.